# Counter Not Incrementing After Adding Items to Cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shopify, liquid

I hope you are doing well. Recently, I encountered an issue with my code after making modifications to remove the popup of the side bar cart. The problem now is that the counter no longer increments when items are added to the cart using the quick add button. Strangely, the counter only reflects the correct number of items added when I refresh the page, which was not the case before I made the code changes.
I would be extremely grateful if anyone could kindly assist me with this issue. Below is the modified code I used to remove the popup:

```
function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
//              cartRecommended(pro_id);
            }, 500);

/*
setTimeout(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('product:added', {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
            variant: cart,
            quantity: 1
        }
    }));
}, 1200);
*/

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");
              
            }, 1600);
          setTimeout(function() {
  //        $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
          }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Which part of this JS code do you expect would be responsible for updating the counter? I don't see where it would be, in what you've written. If you want something to happen in your page after an ajax request, you have to write some JS code to specifically do it. It doesn't happen automatically (because ajax doesn't cause your whole page to be updated, which is basically the whole point of using it).

Comment: Can you please provide the cart html tag. you have to plus one in your cart in frontside as well as backend side

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('product:added', {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
            variant: cart,
            quantity: 1
        }
    }));
}, 1200);
*/..............i apologize for my little knowledge in the code i am modifying....i guess it is related to that part, because when i modify with that code in particular, i lost the functionality of the counter

Comment: So, what happens if you un-comment that section?

Comment: Hey nageen, can you refer to the website through inspect, because i cant locate what you are asking for...https://winnerforce-lb.com/

Comment: Hey ADyson, when i uncomment, the popup of add to cart is enabled again, and the counter works seamlessly, which i dont know how to keep its functionality without the popup

Comment: Why would you not want the popup? It provides information to the user

Comment: P.s. regarding the HTML... if you right-click on the counter value and choose inspect from the submenu, it would take you straight to the source for that part of the page

Comment: Wholesale customers looking to make large orders, such as 1000 items, are encountering a cumbersome 'Add to Cart' process due to the presence of excessive and unnecessary popups.

Comment: Well, surely they still only have to do one action to type in 1000, and then get one popup? They don't have to press "add" 1000 times I hope?? If it's designed sensibly then adding 1000 of an item should be no more difficult than adding 1

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Did you check whether the AJAX request contains the expected data, or whether the server handles that request properly, or whether the response the server sends contains the expected data?

Answer (score 1):

Simply refresh the cart using the custom event coded into the theme code already.

So replace the custom event `product:added` code with `cart:refresh`
change commented code with this code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
            variant: cart,
            quantity: 1
        }
    }));
}, 1200);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey Onkar, your code unfortunately hasnt worked for me.....The items being added through quick add button arent simultaneously reflecting on the current counter.... but only through refresh...Is there any sort of approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
    //            cartRecommended(pro_id);
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart
                    }
                }));
            }, 1200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");

            }, 1600);
            setTimeout(function() {
    //            $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Listen for the 'cart:refresh' event and update the cart count
document.addEventListener('cart:refresh', function() {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
        const cartCount = cart.item_count || 0;
        const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];
        if (CartCount) {
            CartCount.innerHTML = cartCount;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I solved my issue with the code above..

Comment: Glad you solved it, but for a better quality answer you should explain what change you made, compared to your original, so people can understand what the issue was. See also [answer]. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).